# Is it possible to list all branches contained in a tagged release?

Tags: git

I need an easy way to track all branches that were part of a release back to their Jira tickets.

Our git process:

- Create feature branch from develop
- Create pull request to merge back into develop
- When ready for release, create release branch from develop
- Create pull request with this branch for final review to merge into master
- After merge of pull request, tag master with the release number and publish tag

Possible to get a list of all branch names that were merged between to tags?

**UPDATE**

---

This gets me the hash for each commit, but I need the branch name:

```
git log --pretty=oneline v2.0.0-alpha.46...v2.0.0-alpha.45
```

Answer (score 1):

- See the local branches list that contains the tag.

  ```
  $ git branch --contains <tag-name>
  ```
- See the list of branches merged with `master` branch.

  ```
  $ git checkout master
  $ git pull origin master

  $ git branch --merged
  ```